# Recieving 65533 as char value for characters as (à, Ø, æ, æ etc)!

Tags: java, char, short

I've been trying for hours now to figure out why, when  enter a char like Ø in the console through the scanner, to then get the numeric value, I always end up with 65533 (Max value of unsigned short)?

This doesn't seem to be the case for latin characters. Any idea why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] chars = sc.next().toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){

        System.out.println((int)chars[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post some of your code

Comment: It's actualy a really simple simple and straight forward code! i added the code.

Answer (score 9):

65533 = [Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)

i.e. Your character is not being interpreted correctly within the character encoding you are using, and so is being replaced by the fallback value.

Comment: How would I got about fixing it?

Comment: Start by following @Vampire's comment and post your code, so we can replicate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have an encoding problem.
The bytes that come through `System.in` are not in the encoding your `Scanner` uses to translate those bytes to characters.
I guess your `System.in` is in `Cp1252` (Windows default encoding) but your Scanner users `UTF-8` to decode the bytes.
The byte sequence then is not a valid UTF-8 character and so the replacement character is used instead.

If you do `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, System.getProperty("file.encoding"));`, your code should probably work everywhere correctly.

Comment: unfortunately  not! I'm thinking of encode the string to base64 and carry on my operations from there.

Comment: I don't know how that should help, but if it solves your issue, go on with it. But if you ever want to convert that base64 string back to some characters, you still have to konw the encoding of the bytes which for `System.in` should be the content of `file.encoding`.

Comment: This one worked however, `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "Cp1252");`

Comment: Then you maybe set the `file.encoding` to something else after `System.in` alread got created. Be aware that your code will not work properly on Linux, Mac or anything else besides Windows if you hard-code that encoding.